# How to create EC2 instance by docker-machine with exists key pair?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, docker-machine

Use this way to create an instance on aws:

```
docker-machine create \
  -d amazonec2 \
  --amazonec2-region ap-northeast-1 \
  --amazonec2-zone a \
  --amazonec2-ami ami-XXXXXX \
  --amazonec2-keypair-name my_key_pair \
  --amazonec2-ssh-keypath ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
  my_instance
```

Can't connect to it by ssh.

The `my_key_pare` is a name that exist on aws. The `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is local ssh private key. How to set the right value?

I have read the [document](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/aws/#options) but didn't find an example of using both `--amazonec2-keypair-name` and `--amazonec2-ssh-keypath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the file from "Key Pairs" in AWS Console and place it in `~/.ssh`.
Then run

```
docker-machine create \
  -d amazonec2 \
  --amazonec2-region ap-northeast-1 \
  --amazonec2-zone a \
  --amazonec2-ami ami-XXXXXX \
  --amazonec2-ssh-keypath ~/.ssh/keypairfile \
  my_instance
```

Comment: A bit late to the party here but when doing this I get ```Error in driver during machine creation: unable to create key pair: open ~/.ssh/machine-aws-keypair.pem: no such file or directory```. I can only download the .pem file from AWS yet in the docker docs it is written that I need a .pub file (https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/aws/#options).... Any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

### In gitlab-runner using Docker+machine, you have to provide both "amazonec2-keypair-name=XXX",
"amazonec2-ssh-keypath=XXX".

the Keypath should be like /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa and the path should also have id_rsa.pub file with id_rsa. These two file should not be your local generated key, should be the id_rsa, id_rsa.pub of Pem created

The following commands will do the trick,

**cat  faregate-test.pem > /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa**

**ssh-keygen -y -f faregate-test.pem > /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa.pub**

And This will allow you to connect from runner manager instance to the runner provisioned by using your **AWS existing keypair**...

Comment: use markup to ensure commands stand out as commands